# New atm program issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting this error no matter what I do, I have tried to fiddle with global names and the like, I still can't get this error to go away:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled4.py", line 48, in <module>
    transaction()
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled4.py", line 37, in transaction
    deposit()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I really want to get this to function properly so that I can better understand how the code works. But no matter how many forums I look at, I still can't figure out how to fix it.

```
#The purpose of this program is to create a simple ATM environment
#Written by K. Strobach 11/22/13

withdraw = str(0)
deposit = str (0)
end = str(0)

def account():
    print("Hello, welcome to Bank of Python!\nPlease enter your account pin number")
    account = input("Account pin number is 1234: ")
    account = 1234

account()

def accbalance():
    print ("would you like to see your account balance?")
    see = input("Enter Y or N: ")

    if (see == "Y") or (see == "y"):
        balance = str(0)
        print("Current balance: $", str(balance))

accbalance()

def transaction():
    global withdraw
    global deposit
    global end
    print ("Would you like to make a transaction?")
    more = input("Enter Y or N: ")

    if (more == "Y") or (more == "y"):
        print ("Would you like to make a deposit or withdraw? Or would you like to end this transaction?")
        answer = input("Enter D for deposit; W for withdraw; E for end: ")

    if answer[0].lower()=="d":
        deposit()

    if answer[0].lower()=="w":
        withdraw()

    if answer[0].lower()=="e":
        end()

    else:
        print("Thank you for banking with Bank of Python, goodbye!")

transaction()

def deposit(answer):
        if (answer == "D") or (answer == "d"):
            print ("How much would you like to deposit?")
            deposit = input("Enter amount to deposit: ")
            deposit = str(deposit)

            currentbalance = deposit + balance
            print ("Deposited: $", + str(deposit))
            print ("Current Balance: $", + str(currentbalance))

deposit()

def withdraw(answer):    
        if (answer == "W") or (answer == "w"):
            print ("How much would you like to withdrawl?")
            withdraw = input("Enter amount to withdraw: ")
            withdraw = str(withdraw)

            currentbalance = withdraw - balance
            print ("Withdrew: $", + str(withdraw))
            print ("Current Balance: $", + str(currentbalance))

withdraw()

def end(answer):
    if (answer == "E") or (answer == "e"):
        print("Thank you for banking with Bank of Python, goodbye!")
end()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there are many problems with your code that will cause issues well beyond what that error is talking about. I will try and go through as many of them as I can.

First off when you are writing your code please try and keep your functions, separate from your main code, as in define them at the top and in the correct order so that they aren't referenced before they are defined.
e.g. in transaction() you call deposit() but deposit() has yet to be declared. It is defined below it.

As Martijn said, you cannot have both a deposit function and a deposit string. Things will start to get very messy and that is actually what is causing the error that is being shown to you. You repeat this mistake many times so make sure to correct all of the instances.

Next make sure when you call a function you understand what parameters it requires and pass them correctly.
e.g. you define `def deposit(answer):` yet whenever you call deposit you do not pass it anything as answer. I'm not even sure why answer is needed since you already check if it is a 'd' or "d" in transaction.

My next concern is that you are always defining global variables when they are not needed. If a variable is only used in one function as all of yours are, then they need only be defined in that function. Since python has implicit typing instead of declaring the deposit string on the global scope, it will be created when the program runs the line `deposit = input("Enter amount to deposit: ")`. Also you should note that when you try to change deposit to an int you should write `int(deposit)` while you wrote `str(deposit)` which converts it to a string.

My final note (and I'm not sure this is the last of the issues) is that you call deposit(), withdrawal() and end() in your main program for some reason as well as calling them in transaction based on what the user specifies. I think from how the program looks they should only be called in transaction().

Good luck and comment if you can't figure something out.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am now running into the problem of:             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled4.py", line 45, in <module>
    make_transaction()
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled4.py", line 34, in make_transaction
    make_deposit(answer)
NameError: global name 'make_deposit' is not defined                  
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: So I added this to the code:                                make_withdraw = (0)
make_deposit = (0)
make_end = (0)                                                        Then I get:                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled4.py", line 45, in <module>
    make_transaction()
  File "/Users/tonystrobach/Desktop/untitled4.py", line 34, in make_transaction
    make_deposit(answer)

Comment: That is not enough for me to go off. I have pretty much no idea what context any of that is in.

Answer (score 1):

You have both a `deposit` variable *and* a `deposit` function. You cannot have both, you need to rename one or the other.

Python functions are first-class objects. They are bound to names just like values are. They don't live in a separate namespace from your other variables.

Rename the function to `make_deposit()` perhaps:

```
def make_deposit(answer):
    # ...
```

and call that:

```
if answer[0].lower()=="d":
    make_deposit(answer)
```

where you do need to pass in an argument; your function expects one (`answer`).

This applies to `withdraw` and `end` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, I will be messing with my experiment and see what I can do!